# How does Bazel record Cache hit

Tags: build, bazel

Hi all the Bazel users,

I am trying to understand the logging of the cache hit and action execution environment in Bazel.

Firstly, I have noticed that there is a Action_cache.proto file which provides information about the cache hits. Can I assume that it is the local cache hits count?

Secondly, in `ActionResult.java` class there is a `boolean locallyExecuted` which returns true if all spawns of action were executed locally. In my understanding 1 action = 1 spawn, so does it mean 1 action = x spawn, and some spawns could be executed locally/remotely? That would be confusing since the runner's list in `SpawnStats.java` is based on each spawn but when printed in the build summary (in the console) we can see that number of runners = number of actions.

Lastly, in `SpawnMetrics.java` we can find the different execution kinds namely `REMOTE, LOCAL, WORKER, OTHER`. I was just wondering if `WORKER` belongs to local execution?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did [this](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.2.1/remote-caching-debug.html#checking-your-cache-hit-rate) documentation helped?

Answer (score 1):

Calculations for checking the cache rate is mentioned [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.2.1/remote-caching-debug.html#checking-your-cache-hit-rate)

**INFO: 7 processes: 3 remote cache hit, 4 linux-sandbox.**

This means that out of 7 attempted actions, 3 got a remote cache hit and 4 actions did not have cache hits and were executed locally using linux-sandbox strategy. Local cache hits are not included in this summary. If you are getting 0 processes (or a number lower than expected), run bazel clean followed by your build/test command.